# My table sorter jquery isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, tablesorter

This is the actual code I have it is from an example and still I can't figure out what is wrong. This is a basic table I am using to just try this jquery effect out.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"</script>      

 <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> -->
<script type="text.javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    } ; 
    
); 
    
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 
  



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try using this jquery src : `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js` and remove the others. Then use this one for table-sorter : `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js`. You can find many libraries on [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/) ;)

Comment: Tried these 3 just now <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.j‌​s "</script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.‌​28.0/js/jquery.table‌​sorter.min.js "</script> It still doesn't work.

Comment: No. only use `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.j‌​s"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.‌​2‌​8.0/js/jquery.table‌‌​​sorter.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Just tried that and it still is not sorting.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

How to call an external script file.
And a small syntax error in your script (an extra `;`).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>


<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Last Name</th> 
            <th>First Name</th> 
            <th>Email</th> 
            <th>Due</th> 
            <th>Web Site</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Smith</td> 
            <td>John</td> 
            <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
            <td>$50.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Bach</td> 
            <td>Frank</td> 
            <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
            <td>$50.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Doe</td> 
            <td>Jason</td> 
            <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
            <td>$100.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Conway</td> 
            <td>Tim</td> 
            <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
            <td>$50.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```